# How to move multiple bitmaps in single canvas android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I want to move multiple bitmap on the same canvas. Using below code i can  move one bitmap when  touch on the screen but, i can't identify the touch event on the bitmap so that i couldn't move specific bitmap.

```
public class DrawTopologyView extends View {
Paint paint = new Paint();
Bitmap zed_bitMap, lamp_on_bitmap, fan_on_bitmap, ac_on_bitmap;

int START_X = 5;
int START_Y = 5;

float x = 500-24,y=START_Y;

public DrawTopologyView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    zed_bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
            R.drawable.zed);
    lamp_on_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
            R.drawable.lamp_on);
    fan_on_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
            R.drawable.fan_on);
    ac_on_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
            R.drawable.ac_on);

}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    int CENTER_X = canvas.getWidth() / 2 - 24;
    int CENTER_Y = canvas.getHeight() / 2 - zed_bitMap.getHeight();

    int FULL_WIDTH = canvas.getWidth();
    int FULL_HEIGHT = canvas.getHeight();

    canvas.drawBitmap(zed_bitMap, CENTER_X, CENTER_Y, paint);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    paint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[] { 5, 5, 5, 5 }, 0));

    canvas.drawBitmap(ac_on_bitmap, START_X, START_Y, paint);
    canvas.drawLine(START_X + 48, START_Y + 48, CENTER_X + 10,
            CENTER_Y + 10, paint);

    canvas.drawLine(250, START_Y + 48, CENTER_X + 10, CENTER_Y + 10, paint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(lamp_on_bitmap, 250 - 24, START_Y, paint);

    canvas.drawLine(500, START_Y + 48, CENTER_X + 10, CENTER_Y + 10, paint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(fan_on_bitmap, x,y, paint);


    // canvas.drawLine(FULL_WIDTH-40,FULL_HEIGHT-120,CENTER_X+30,CENTER_Y+30,
    // paint);
    // canvas.drawBitmap(light_off_bitmap, FULL_WIDTH-60-24,FULL_HEIGHT-130,
    // paint);

}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

    }
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
        x = (int) event.getX();
        y = (int) event.getY();

        invalidate();
    }

        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

        x = (int) event.getX();
        y = (int) event.getY();
        Log.d(APPConstant.LOG_TAG, ".................." + x + "......" + y);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), ".................." + x + "......" + y,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        invalidate();
        break;
    }
    return true;
}



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class SimpleDrag extends View {



private final int INVALID_INDEX = -1;

private final int mTotalItems = 5;

private ArrayList<Rect> mItemsCollection;

private ArrayList<Point> mActiveDragPoints;

private ArrayList<Rect>  mActiveRects;


private Paint mPaint;

/**
 * @param context  
 * @return of type SimpleDrag
 * Constructor function
 * @since Feb 19, 2013 
 * @author rajeshcp
 */
public SimpleDrag(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

/**
 * @param context
 * @param attrs  
 * @return of type SimpleDrag
 * Constructor function
 * @since Feb 19, 2013 
 * @author rajeshcp
 */
public SimpleDrag(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

/**
 * @param context
 * @param attrs
 * @param defStyle  
 * @return of type SimpleDrag
 * Constructor function
 * @since Feb 19, 2013 
 * @author rajeshcp
 */
public SimpleDrag(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.view.View#onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)
 * @since Feb 19, 2013
 * @author rajeshcp 
 */
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
    for( Rect rect : mItemsCollection)
    {
        canvas.drawRect(rect, mPaint);
    }
}


/**
 * @param of type null
 * @return of type null
 * function which will initialize the view
 * @since Feb 20, 2013
 * @author rajeshcp
 */
private void init()
{
    mActiveRects      = new ArrayList<Rect>(mTotalItems);
    mActiveDragPoints = new ArrayList<Point>(mTotalItems);
    mItemsCollection  = new ArrayList<Rect>();
    for( int i = 0; i < mTotalItems; i++)
    {
        Rect rect = new Rect(i * 100, i * 100, (i + 1) * 100, (i + 1) * 100);
        mItemsCollection.add(rect);
    }
    mPaint     = new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG | Paint.DITHER_FLAG | Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
}





/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.view.View#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)
 * @since Feb 19, 2013
 * @author rajeshcp 
 */
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    final int action  = event.getActionMasked();
    final int pointer = event.getActionIndex();

    switch (action) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
        Point touchDown = new Point((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
        lookForIntersection(touchDown);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL :
        mActiveDragPoints.removeAll(mActiveDragPoints);
        mActiveRects.removeAll(mActiveRects);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
        int count = 0;
        for(Rect rect : mActiveRects)
        {
            Point curretPoint = new Point((int)event.getX(count), (int)event.getY(count));
            moveRect(curretPoint, mActiveDragPoints.get(count), rect);
            count++;
        }
        Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Active Rects" + mActiveRects.size());
        Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Active Points" + mActiveDragPoints.size());
        invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN :
        touchDown = new Point((int)event.getX(pointer), (int)event.getY(pointer));
        lookForIntersection(touchDown);
        //Log.d(getClass().getName(), "ACTION_POINTER_DOWN" + pointer);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP :
        int index = getIntersectionRectIndex(new Point((int)event.getX(pointer), (int)event.getY(pointer)));
        if( index != INVALID_INDEX )
        {
            Rect rect = mItemsCollection.get(index);
            mActiveDragPoints.remove(mActiveRects.indexOf(rect));
            mActiveRects.remove(rect);
        }

        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return true;
}


/**
 * @param touchDown of type Point
 * @return of type null
 * function which will find the 
 * intersecting rect and add to the 
 * active collection
 * @since Feb 20, 2013
 * @author rajeshcp
 */
private void lookForIntersection(Point touchDown)
{
    final int index = getIntersectionRectIndex(touchDown);

    if( index != INVALID_INDEX )
    {
        final Rect rect = mItemsCollection.get(index);
        if( mActiveRects.indexOf(rect) == INVALID_INDEX )
        {
            mActiveDragPoints.add(touchDown);
            mActiveRects.add(mItemsCollection.get(index));
        }
    }
    Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Active Rects" + mActiveRects.size());
    Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Active Points" + mActiveDragPoints.size());

}




/**
 * @param point of type Point
 * @return of type int 
 * function which will return the index of 
 * the rect contaning the given point
 * @since Feb 20, 2013
 * @author rajeshcp
 */
private int getIntersectionRectIndex(final Point point)
{
    int index = INVALID_INDEX;
    for(Rect rect : mItemsCollection)
    {
        if( rect.contains(point.x, point.y) )
        {
            index = mItemsCollection.indexOf(rect);
            break;
        }
    }
    return index;
}


/**
 * @param currentPoint of type Point
 * @param prevPoint of type Point 
 * @param rect of type Rect
 * @return of type null
 * function which will move the change the 
 * bounds of teh rect
 * @since Feb 20, 2013
 * @author rajeshcp
 */
private void moveRect(Point currentPoint, Point prevPoint, final Rect rect)
{
    int xMoved = currentPoint.x - prevPoint.x;
    int yMoved = currentPoint.y - prevPoint.y;
    rect.set(rect.left + xMoved, rect.top + yMoved, rect.right + xMoved, rect.bottom + yMoved);
    mActiveDragPoints.set(mActiveDragPoints.indexOf(prevPoint), currentPoint);
}

}
```

This allow you to select more than one bitmap at a time as well. This case I'm only using rectangles you can fill this rectangles with bitmaps.

Comment: First of all thank God.This works and your code runs thought.Thank you very much Rajesh CP.at last thanks to stackoverflow also.

Comment: Thanx a lot. It was a pain for me@Rajesh

Comment: @Rajesh CP: Actually i have to use bitmaps,So i have placed bitmaps inside rectangle,but the problem is rectangle's background red colors seen behind bitmap.can we omit this problem.

Comment: @Ahesanali this could be because your bit map and the rectangle geometry isn't matching. This case you can avoid drawing the rectangle and draw the bitmap directly using the drawbitmap api of canvas.

Comment: @Triode seems like it's too long and i have left this project so i can't say anything about this right now.

Comment: @Triode is it possible to use this logic for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52429340/select-multiple-bitmaps-using-ontouchevent