# How to move object relative to movement user inputs through touch?

Tags: java, android, andengine

Okay so say we have a graph with a ball on it at (200,200) and we swipe our finger from (0,0) to (100,100) how do I go about moving the ball to (300,300)? This should be simple but it is really hurting my head! This is the code I have so far (using andengine)

```
float currentX=0;
float lastX=0;
float currentY=0;
float lastY=0;
@Override

public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {

    // If a user moves their finger on the device

    if(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
        // Set our marble's position to the touched area on the screen

        if(pSceneTouchEvent.getX()!=lastX){
            currentX = lastX- pSceneTouchEvent.getX();

        }
        if(pSceneTouchEvent.getY()!=lastY){
            currentY = lastY- pSceneTouchEvent.getY();

        }
        //float x1 = pSceneTouchEvent.getX()-mMarbleSprite.getX();
        mMarbleSprite.setPosition(currentX,currentY );

        lastX = pSceneTouchEvent.getX();
        lastY = pSceneTouchEvent.getY();


        return true;
    }

    return false;

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881790/how-to-move-multiple-bitmaps-in-single-canvas-android/20881882#20881882

Answer (score 0):

I think you can take a look on Property Animation in Android. Here is the developer reference. It's easy to implement and understand.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html

Answer (score 0):

```
currentX = lastX- pSceneTouchEvent.getX();
```

This assign is giving you values close to zero every time (You are calculating the delta of each touch relative to the last one). Try to set the touch position directly.

```
currentx = pSceneTouchEvent.getX();
```